# Android RatingBar highlights the star sooner than expected

Tags: android, ratingbar

I have a RatingBar component in the application for which I have the following configuration:

```
android:numStars="5"
android:stepSize="1.0"
```

The problem is as soon as the touch crosses one pixel from the section of the next star, the next star is highlighted too. Is there a way to wait until the finger touch is more area from the next star and only then highlight it.

NOTE: I don't use PNGs for the stars.

Comment: minHeight and maxHeight to the size of the icons.

Comment: @SuryaPrakashKushawah I wrote a NOTE that I don't use icons :)

Answer (score 0):

In case your are willing to try a RatingBar different from the stock one, you might wanna try a library I made: [SimpleRatingBar](https://github.com/FlyingPumba/SimpleRatingBar).

It solves the problem that you mention by drawing the fill only when touch event is greater or equal than `stepSize / 4`. This makes the behaviour a bit more smooth and less "jumpy".

It features:

- Fully working `android:layout_width`: it can be set to `wrap_content`, `match_parent` or abritary dp.
- Arbitrary number of stars.
- Arbitrary step size.
- Size of stars can be controlled exactly or by setting a maximum size.
- Customizable colors in normal state (border, fill and background of stars and rating bar).
- Customizable colors in pressed state (border, fill and background of stars and rating bar).
- Customizable size separation between stars.
- Customizable border width of stars.
- Customizable stars corner radius.
- Allows to set OnRatingBarChangeListener and OnClickListener
- Stars fill can be set to start from left to right or from right to left (RTL language support).
- AnimationBuilder integrated in the view to set rating programatically with animation.

[Here is a preview of it](https://github.com/FlyingPumba/SimpleRatingBar/raw/master/images/sample.gif).

You can find it in `jcenter`, `Maven Central` and `JitPack`. So in your `build.gradle` file just add to your dependencies:

`compile 'com.iarcuschin:simpleratingbar:0.1.+'`